# Null result after taking a photo

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I need to take a photo, get the full-size file to send to a server. With thumbnails it works fine, but with i can't recover the full-size photo. I read and copied most of the code from google tutorial on [android developers web page](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html).

I'm doing this:

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        mPhotoFile = null;
        try {
            mPhotoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }            
        if (mPhotoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    mCurrentPhotoPath);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp;
    File storageDir;
    if (StorageUtils.isExternalStorageWritable()) {
        storageDir = StorageUtils.getExternalStorageAppDir(getActivity());
    } else {
        storageDir = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    }
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,
            ".jpg",
            storageDir
    );
    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;        
        Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions); // returns null
        mImageAdapter.addImage(bitmap);
    }
}
```

This line (inside onActivityResult returns null):

```
Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
```

I read a lot of posts about camera issues but nothing seems to work. I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**Note:** i test the code in an emulator and in a real device. Same result.

Comment: Make sure that you are saving `mCurrentPhotoPath` in the saved instance state `Bundle`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37039085/android-inconsistent-picture-saving-with-getexternalfilesdir/37039274.

Comment: Yes, i am saving it. The picture is not generated in mCurrentPhotoPath, so maybe the problem is in the creation of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in this line:

```
bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
```

The google doc about bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds says:

> If set to true, the decoder will return null (no bitmap), but the
>   out... fields will still be set, allowing the caller to query the
>   bitmap without having to allocate the memory for its pixels.

After removing this line the image was returned ok.